# Raw use of parameterized class on Android Studio

Tags: android, bottom-sheet, parameterized-class

I have this code on my Android project:

```
final BottomSheetBehavior infoBottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(findViewById(R.id.info_view));
        infoBottomSheetBehavior.addBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
                if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_DRAGGING) {
                    infoBottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {
            }
        });
```

And the next warning appears over BottomSheetBehavior: `Raw use of parameterized class 'BottomSheetBehavior'`

Does anybody know how to avoid this warning?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Ok, here is the so basic answer from a coffee talk...

```
final BottomSheetBehavior<View> infoBottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(findViewById(R.id.info_view));
        infoBottomSheetBehavior.addBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
                if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_DRAGGING) {
                    infoBottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {
            }
        });
```

I've just missed the `<View>`

Comment: I remember this warning did not come before,am i right?

Comment: You're fully right, my friend. It appeared suddenly during a quick updates some months ago.